# How can I create custom TextToSpeech audio files on buttonclick?

Tags: java, android, file, audio, text-to-speech

With this code i want to create custom TextToSpeech files with the text written in the Textedit.
 The User can write something in the TextEdit and the TextToSpeech converts this into speech and then I want to create this speech as a audiofile, which I can share.
But now I dont know where my error is and I don't know further.
Could you please help me :)

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

import static de.fresenborg.aufeinwort4.R.id.editText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, View.OnClickListener {

private TextToSpeech tts;
private static String fileLocation;
private static String text;
public TextToSpeechFile(String fLocation, String txt) {
    fileLocation = fLocation;
    text = txt;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    final EditText wassoll = (EditText) findViewById(editText);
    tts.speak(wassoll.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

    ImageButton Sharebutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Sharebutton);
    Sharebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            public static void createFile(){
                TextToSpeech tts;
                HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap();
                myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, text);
                tts.synthesizeToFile(text, myHashRender, fileLocation);
                final int utteranceId = 1;
                File destinationFile = new File(getCacheDir(), utteranceId + ".wav");
                int utteranceId++;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    tts.synthesizeToFile(TextToSpeech.ACTION_TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED, null, destinationFile, utteranceId);
                } else {
                    Bundle params = new Bundle();
                    params.putString(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, utteranceId);
                    tts.synthesizeToFile(TextToSpeech.ACTION_TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED, params, destinationFile.getPath());)

                        tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new     TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onUtteranceCompleted(String s) {
                            if (s.equals(utteranceId)) {

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });


}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);


}






@Override
public void onInit(int arg0) {
    tts.setLanguage(Locale.GERMAN);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}



}
```

This is my XML:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Was soll ich sagen?"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="8"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:text="@string/wassoll" />

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/Sharebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:background="@null"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/share" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/button_sag_es" />
```